# JavaScript: find the parent div given the class of the children

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code looks like this

```
<div id="resultsdiv">
  <div id="xxxx" class="container">
    <a class="results"> </a>
    <a class="results"> </a>
    <div id="zzzz" class="default">
      <p> some default data </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a button called "default only" and When i click the button, all results class elements should be hidden and only the default class div should be displayed and in case any of the container div doesn't have any default class div, it should be hidden too, and once i click the button again the whole thing should be reversed Here my inner divs are dynamically created so I do not have an idea what their IDs are, so is there a way to achieve what I am looking for by only using the class names?

Comment: I'm not seeing *any* `button`s in there.

Comment: pure javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Sinne R anything is fine

Comment: Are you looking for a pure javascript only approach?  jQuery let's you grab collections of DOM elements filtered by class name relatively painlessly.  Otherwise you'd be grabbing a collection of all (div) child nodes from your resultsdiv and iterating over them looking at className property.

Comment: just use jquery $('.yourClassName').hide() on classes you want to hide

Answer (score 2):

If a jQuery solution is ok for you, then here's the code:

```
$("#default_only_button_id").on("click", function() {
    $(".container div:not(.default)").toggle();

    if($(".container .default").length == 0) {
        $(".container").toggle();
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Corrected according to @ckarmann suggestion

EDIT2:

I didn't actually test the edited code, but it should work ;)

Comment: I would also like to hide the results class div, if the container div contains a default class div and then the button is clicked

Comment: .hide() would work as well similarly to the .css()   or even .toggle() if you want to show/hide with each click

Comment: Shouldn't the selector be something more like ".container div:not(.default)" ? http://jsfiddle.net/G7U3L/

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I'm getting this right - your question implies that you want to hide all divs without the default class inside a div with class equal to container. Now you're saying that you want to hide divs with result class if the container div contains divs with class default. I'm confused :). Which one is it?

Comment: When i click the button, all results class divs should be hidden and only the default class divs should be displayed and incase any of the container div doesn't have any default class divs, it should be hidden too, and once i click the button again the whole thing should be reversed

Comment: @EliteOctagon I know, that I can use .hide(), but I'm just accustomed to using .css function

Comment: @nienawiedzony the code that you have given is hiding my default class elements

Comment: @nienawiedzony can you please check the latest edited question, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(className)
```

Read more about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

In jQuery use: `$('.results').hide();`
where `.results` is a CSS class selector, you can read more at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is not supported in older browsers (notably IE8).  If you're targeting such an audience you may consider something more like this for a pure JS route:

```
var x = document.getElementById("resultsdiv").getElementsByTagName("div");
for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    if(x[i].className == "results") //check other className's as desired
        x[i].style.display = "none";
```

You also have tools such as `parentNode` to navigate the DOM, see [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/parentNode).

Note, even with this approach there still may be some other cross-browser worries.  For example, class properties that contain multiple space-separated classes instead of a single value.  One of the reasons why a framework like jQuery is helpful.